# Unescape escaped emojis in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, escaping

I am trying to unescape a string with escaped characters (emojis) in Python 3.
I have no luck with all these tries:

```
import html
import json
from werkzeug.utils import unescape

a = 'foo \ud83d\udcde\ud83d\udce7 bar'

html.unescape(a)
a.encode().decode()
json.loads(f'{{"text":"{a}"}}').get('text')
unescape(a)
```

All don't work.

Any ideas for a lean and simple way? Maybe a library?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '\\ud83d\\udcde'.encode("latin_1")
                    .decode("raw_unicode_escape")
                    .encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')
                    .decode('utf-16')
                    .encode("raw_unicode_escape")
                    .decode("latin_1")

# \U0001f4de
```

---

```
a = '\\ud83d\\udcde'.encode("latin_1")
                    .decode("raw_unicode_escape")
                    .encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')
                    .decode('utf-16')
#
```

You need a series of encoding and decoding to convert the 4-digit unicode escape to 8-digit unicode escape. More on Unicodes [here](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/python-2.6.9-docs-html/howto/unicode.html).

---

1. `.encode('latin1')` will give you the bytes: `b'\\ud83d\\udcde'`
2. `.decode("raw_unicode_escape").encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass')` will give you the 2-digit hex escapes: `b'\xff\xfe=\xd8\xde\xdc'`
3. `.decode('utf-16')` decoding it using utf-16 will give you the emoji:  (might be difficult to see the emoji in SO dark mode)
4. `.encode("raw_unicode_escape")` encoding it again will give you 8-digit Unicode as bytes: `b'\\U0001f4de'`
5. `.decode("latin_1")` finally, decoding the latin1 back will give you the 8-digit Unicode String: `\U0001f4de`

Comment: I have 2 issue with your suggestion. My source string has no double backslashes. And I used foo and bar, but how about other unicode chars in the string besides latin1, e.g. "foo 愛 foo \ud83d\udcde\ud83d\udce7 bar".

Comment: 1. You can easily figure out a solution for single to double slashes. Single slash needs to be escaped.

Comment: 2. `'foo \\ud83d\\udcde\\ud83d\\udce7 bar'` is working perfectly fine.

Comment: 3. You did not mention `愛` characters in the original question. Please consider adding a second question for that with my solution as attempt. People have spent time and effort into writing solutions for you, you cannot change the question after that.

Comment: Great, your second method worked for me. I wanted to put an emoji string in a cookie and get it back on the input form. Cookie didn't accept the raw emoji string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at this library: https://pypi.org/project/demoji/.
And you can also try

```
print("\U0001F600")
```

Which will output this

And you can also try this

```
s = ''
print(s.encode('unicode-escape'))
```

which will output this

```
b'\\U0001f600'
```

Please also visit this website to get a full list. https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: The OP does not have 8-digit unicode as input, but has 4-digit unicodes.